# For em Matriz VBA

Tags: array, vba, matriz, for

Tenho um banco de dados composto por dois vetores: `u=(a,b,c)` e `v=(1,2,3)`
Em outra planilha, tenho dois vetores em branco `x` e `y`. Preciso que, ao completar uma entrada de `x` (vinda de `u`), o código me retorne a entrada correspondente de `v` em `x`.

Por exemplo, se `x = (b,c,b)`, então `y =(2,3,2)`

Obrigada!

Comment: Oi Mariana. Você já tentou usar as funções [`vlookup` ou `hlookup`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/181213/pt-br)?

Comment: Olá Luiz, na verdade minha dúvida é em como obter um retorno com os dados do segundo vetor. Todos os vetores já estão definidos. No vetor x, eu que vou digitar um valor, e se esse valor for igual a uma das entradas do vetor u, então eu quero que ele me retorne a entrada correspondente do vetor y no vetor v.
Eu acho que preciso usar a função IF e a FOR, mas não estou conseguindo

Comment: Eu entendi depois, por isso removi o comentário e postei outro. Adicione um *screenshot* de como está a sua planilha. Mas uma ideia é você usar uma das funções de *lookup* que eu mencionei para procurar pela letra e devolver o valor. Você provavelmente não precisa de VBA. Mais um exemplo: http://blog.luz.vc/excel/como-usar-funcao-procv-vlookup-excel/

Comment: Eu estou optando por VBA pois os vetores serão muito grandes

Comment: Se o Excel consegue armazenar/representar, não faz diferença alguma. As funções nativas do Excel funcionam suficientemente bem. VBA só é necessário quando você precisa construir algo que não dá pra fazer só usando os recursos nativos do Excel. :)

Comment: ok, vou tentar, obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: Por nada. Se conseguir resolver, por favor poste você mesmo uma resposta com a solução detalhada. Assim você ajuda também outras pessoas que possam ter a mesma dúvida no futuro. :)

Comment: P.S.: Estou imaginando que os valores de cada componente dos vetores estão em colunas ou linhas separadas, e por isso dá pra usar as funções de *lookup* tranquilamente. Se for uma string só, você vai precisar separar tudo (e ai, nesse caso, talvez precisará mesmo de VBA). Por isso que eu disse, poste mais detalhes de como está o conteúdo do seu arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Crie um banco de dados ex.:

```
A1 B1
x   1
y   2
z   3
```

Em A1 crie uma validação de dados tipo lista:

```
=$A$2:$A$4
```

Vá na aba Formulas, Gerenciador de nomes:

> novo: x refere-se a B2
>
> novo: y refere-se a B3
>
> novo: z refere-se a B4

em B1 crie Validação de dados tipo lista:

```
=Indireto(substituir(A1;"_";" ")
```

Pronto, o que voce escolher em A1, será opção correspondente em B1. mas nao necessariamente A1 deve ser lista suspensa, apenas para o caso de garantir que o valor de A1 terá correspondente em B1.

Se você for fazer isso pelo `vba` será muito extenso.